# Using text.js with require.js how can I create one template html file but grab each script template individually?

Tags: javascript, jquery, templates, requirejs, underscore.js

I'm using require.js and text.js to load a template file that has a bunch of `<script>` templates in it:

e.g. /scripts/templates/comments.html

```
<script type="text/template" id="js-comment-reply-tmpl">
// html in here
</script>

<script type="text/template" id="js-comment-edit-tmpl">
// html in here
</script>
```

And because using underscore's template system (or any similar js micro-templating system), this file itself gets loaded as a string. Is there a smart way to just grab each template from within that file? e.g. `$(template).html()` wrap it in jQuery and then do a `find()` or something on it? I'd essentially have to place it into the DOM first though, so that would probably be slow as hell and I might as well just not even load it with text.js and just pluck it out of the DOM initially.

My other thought is to split them each into their own files, but then that would slow down on request time (although I'd probably just end up using r.js with node to minify this all in the end anyway so it wouldn't matter).

e.g. /scripts/templates/comment_reply.html

```
<script type="text/template" id="js-comment-reply-tmpl">
// html in here
</script>
```

e.g. /scripts/templates/comment_edit.html
    
    // html in here

What's the best/most efficient way to do this?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I would advise moving each template into it's own file and loading them all separately. Some of the advantages of doing so are:

- **Easier maintainance** - Searching for a template in a project is easier if they all have their own names and it also reduces hassle with source control conflicts if developers aren't all editing the same file.
- **Portability** - If you end up using a templating system that can be used on the server (like Mustache) then the templates are already easy to share between front and back-end.

The main disadvantage that you already highlighted are the extra requests, but you should definitely not be going to production without building your scripts with r.js so this shouldn't be a problem

Comment: Yeah good points... This is what I was thinking of doing. I appreciate the recommendation.

Comment: I do have to say though, what happens if I need 2 templates for say comment_delete? E.g. `<script type="text/template" id="js-comment-delete-undo-tmpl">` and `<script type="text/template" id="js-comment-delete-tmpl">`?

Comment: If they are only different by a small amount then you could re-use the same template and pass different data to it. An example here - http://goo.gl/shQb3 Uses has_date or has_image depending on the type of data it renders. Otherwise, just create two separate templates and load them when necessary. Maybe with something like RequireJS.